# Merge base64 images

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have several layers of KineticJS canvases which are all on top of each other. I'd like to be able to export these as a PNG. I can export each of the layers by using the `.toDataURL()` function, but I'd like them all as one image.

Is there a way to merge all the base64 strings?

Comment: It would be easier to draw all the layers onto a single canvas. `drawImage(img, x, y)` can take a canvas element as its first argument. Simply draw each your canvases (via `drawImage`) onto a new master canvas, and then call `.toDataURL()` on that master canvas.

Comment: try this, https://jsfiddle.net/1hcrvc16/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@apsillers has the right idea--combine each image on top of each other and export the final composite.

**KineticJS has a shortcut to export all layers combined: `stage.toDataURL().`**

`stage.toDataURL` will export the combination of all its layers to a dataUrl.

Warning: As with all canvas image exports, you must be sure all your images are CORS compliant.

Here's example code:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
    container: 'container',
    width: 400,
    height: 400
});
var layer1 = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer1);
var layer2 = new Kinetic.Layer();
stage.add(layer2);


var img1=new Image();
img1.onload = function() {
    var image1 = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: img1,
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    });
    layer1.add(image1);
    layer1.draw();
}
img1.src="yourCORScompliantImage1.png";

var img2=new Image();
img2.onload = function() {
    var image2 = new Kinetic.Image({
      x: 0,
      y: 0,
      image: img2,
      width: 100,
      height: 100
    });
    layer2.add(image2);
    layer2.draw();
}
img2.src="yourCORScompliantImage2.png";

$("#export").click(function(){
        stage.toDataURL({
          callback: function(dataUrl) {
              window.open(dataUrl);
          }
        });
});
```

Comment: Can't find much info about CORS images. Is this only needed if the images are used within the canvas? I don't actually use any within the canvases, so am I alright? Also, if the base64 string is too long, might it not work as a URL? Should I `var image = window.open(); image.document.write('<img src="'+dataUrl+'"/>');`. Both options work fine for now, just worried about big strings. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: No potential problems if all your canvas content is created without images.  But if you want to learn more about CORS and images, see "cross domain security". Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

you can make svg containing

```
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image1/png;base64,...">
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image2/png;base64,...">
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image3/png;base64,...">
<image width="100" height="100" xlink:href="data:image4/png;base64,...">
```

will be 4 layered svg